# SQL Query - wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
   Tickets T
INNER JOIN 
   Facts F on T.Ticket_Nummer = F.Ticket_Nummer
INNER JOIN 
   Dates D on D.DatetimeKey = F.Datum
WHERE 
   F.Datum in 
        (SELECT 
           max(x.Datum)
         FROM 
           Facts x 
         WHERE x.Ticket_Nummer = F.Ticket_Nummer 
         and 
             X.Status in ('HD50', 'SD50', 'HD53', 'HD55', 'SD55', 'HD56')  
         and 
             cast(F.Datum as date) between '09.05.2022' and '13.05.2022'  
         and 
             D.Process_Code not like 'Analyse') 
ORDER BY D.Bereich,T.Gruppe, Datum
```

So it should show me all results with 'HD50', 'SD50', 'HD53', 'HD55', 'SD55', 'HD56' in the specified timeline ...

I get the above results but I also get some results with HD05, HD16 what I think is not possible because I said only results with HD/SD >= 50.

What may be the problem here?

**SAMPLE DATA:**

| No | Status | Cast(…as Date) | Date original |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14539 | HD05 | 12.05.2022 | 12.05.2022 13:11 |
| 14539 | SD55 | 12.05.2022 | 12.05.2022 13:11 |

I was expecting results with 'HD50', 'SD50', 'HD53', 'HD55', 'SD55', 'HD56' not HD05.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: If you have two records with same date, that date is max date, and status = HD50 and XYZ, then both will be returned.

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: If you have two records with same date, that date is max date, and status = HD50 and XYZ, then both will be returned. – 
Salman A
 i guess this is the problem ... do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to show us the sample data with the expected result. So that we can propose a better way to write the query

Comment: Can't you simply use Fact_Tickets FT instead of Fact_Tickets x to do this condition?: Status in ('HD50', 'SD50', 'HD53', 'HD55', 'SD55', 'HD56')

Comment: Can't you simply use Fact_Tickets FT instead of Fact_Tickets x to do this condition?: Status in ('HD50', 'SD50', 'HD53', 'HD55', 'SD55', 'HD56') – 
Jonas Metzler
35 mins ago --> No if i do this i get about 300 results less ...

Comment: If I undertand your question correctly, you just WANT to get less results: "...but I also get some results with HD05, HD16..."

Comment: in the query i now used: AND F.Status not in ('HD06','HD10','HD13','HD14','HD15','HD16','HD20','HD21','HD22','HD24','HD40','HD42','HD45','HD49','HD50','HD53','HD55','HD56','HD57','SD06','SD09','SD10','SD11','SD15','SD15.1','SD30','SD45','SD50','SD55','SD57') so now it works